# RAILS: Word_wrap for a long line of text across multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use word wrap such that it can wrap a single long string of text within an array on multiple lines.

I found the link below to be somewhat helpful:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/word_wrap

I copied the regex listed in the link above, which matches a single long string within an array:

```
def breaking_wrap_wrap(msg, col = 80)
  msg.gsub(/(.{1,#{col}})( +|$\n?)|(.{1,#{col}})/,"\\1\\3\n")
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to fix the regex to match the string within the array:

`` undefined method `gsub' for ["adsgagsdgds"]:Array ``

I couldn't get it to work in Rubular or another gsub testing tool, so was wondering if anyone knew how to match the array above and break the line if a single string in the array is greater than 80 characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is `txt` an Array? Aren't you expecting a String?

Comment: `gsub` can be used on **String** only, here it seems **msg** returns **Array**

Comment: you can try this  `msg.last.gsub(/(.{1,#{col}})( +|$\n?)|(.{1,#{col}})/,"\\1\\3\n")`

Comment: Amit, that only displays the first letter in the string.